# @Input ony available in Life Cycle Hooks

Tags: angular, typescript

The basketList objest is available in the html and in the Life Cycle Hook ngOnInit. However, when I try to access it with a function **this.set()** defined outside the hook then it doesn't work.

```
export class MenuOrderItemComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() basketList: any;

  set(): void{
    setInterval(function(){
      console.log(this.basketList);
      console.log(this.basketList.length);
    },3000);
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('item');
    console.log(this.basketList);
    console.log(this.basketList.length);
    this.set();
  }
```

I'm getting undefined for this.basketList and the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` for the second console.log in **this.set()**

Comment: Try using a lambda function instead of `function(){}`

Comment: @GCSDC thank you. I literally changed " setInterval(function(){ " to " setInterval(() => { " and it worked. Do you know what the reason is for "function" not working though?

Comment: Because "this" isn't what you think it is in your original code. Try logging "console.log(this)" inside the setInterval function in both cases.

Comment: I've posted a full explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue is about scope. You can either use `arrow function` or `bind` the scope manually.

```
export class MenuOrderItemComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() basketList: any;

  set = (): void => {
  //    ^^^^^^^^^ Here

    setInterval(() => {
        //    ^^^^^^^^^ And here

       ...
    },3000);
  }

  ......
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get the updated value of `'basketList'` in `ngOnchange()` life cycle hook-
    `@input() id: number;
     @input() name: string;
     ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
     console.log(changes);
     }
     // Output
     {id: SimpleChange, name: SimpleChange}`

And by setter method of typescript-

```
 @Input() set basketList(data: any) {
 // you might do something special in here
 this.basketList= data;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `function() {}` defines a new `this` object, so by using `this` inside it you're actually acessing a different `this` object, not the `MenuOrderItemComponent`'s one (and this other `this` object does not have a `basketList` property).

To solve this, you may use an arrow function, which does not have its own `this`, which means that it will use the parent's `this` (as you're expecting):

```
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(this.basketList);
  console.log(this.basketList.length);
},3000);
```

For more info, check the **Arrow functions** section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)